# Can I change a JSONB key with a query?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB column in a postgres database. The json object it holds is structured like this:

```
{
  "kws": {},
  "distinct": 0,
  "count": 0
}
```

Some of the records have nonzero/non-null values, of course.

A colleague has inserted quite a few records where he made the key *total_count* instead of *count*. Is there a way to change that key with a query rather than retrieving each record and updating the field?

Comment: Use `||` and `-` JSONB operators. DB-fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p8bAPgca92K1A7kf4TTWtV/0)

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the current content, using the magic `-` and the jsonb function [jsonb_insert()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html);

```
CREATE TABLE foo(j jsonb);

INSERT INTO foo(j) VALUES ('{
  "kws": {},
  "distinct": 0,
  "total_count": 0
}'::jsonb)
RETURNING *;

UPDATE foo
SET j = (jsonb_insert(j, '{counter}', j->'total_count')) - 'total_count'
RETURNING *;
```

The new key will be named `counter` and is using the old value for total_count.

Comment: Notice that `jsonb_insert` returns `NULL` when `j->'total_count'` does not exist. You'll at least want to safeguard this with `WHERE j ? 'total_count'`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`?`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) path-exists operator to narrow down the update, the `jsonb_set()` accordingly, with `create_if_missing` parameter set to `true`, then remove the unwanted key with a `-`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/OFomjBFT)

```sql
update my_table
set jbdata = jsonb_set(jbdata,
                       '{count}',
                       coalesce(jbdata->'count',jbdata->'total_count'),
                       true)-'total_count'
where jbdata ? 'total_count'
```

You can speed things up by combining that with a [`jsonb_ops` GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING):

```sql
create index jsonb_ops_idx on my_table using gin(jbdata jsonb_ops);
```

Comment: `create_if_missing` is `true` by default, I wouldn't pass it.

Comment: I wouldn't either, but using it in the example above looked like a decent way of underlining `create_if_missing` is what's going to happen if the function with a `_set` in the name doesn't find the thing it was meant to set. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (than the `jsonb_insert` + `-` shown by @FrankHeikens) is to use a subquery that expands all key-value pairs (using `jsonb_each`) and re-aggregates them (using `jsonb_object_agg`) while literally re-keying them:

```
UPDATE example
SET foo = (
  SELECT jsonb_object_agg(CASE key WHEN 'total_count' THEN 'counter' ELSE key END, value)
  FROM jsonb_each(foo)
)
WHERE foo ? 'total_count';
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/tbCKmfW2))</sup>